# Is there a way to control of DataCollector calling sequence in MsTest

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, mstest

We use MsTest and Tfs as testing infrastructure.
Several custom dataCollectors was installed onto test machine. But I would like to control the process of calling these collectors. Is there a way to configure the scheme of how QtAgent will load and execute DataCollectors. I've digged out all msdn but without success.
I need get know when all data collectors have completed their work to run reboot process and other auxiliary actions

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with only your custom data collectors then you can build this logic yourself. Create a common data collector class that all your custom collectors derive from and `count++` all the session start events received. Similarly `count--` the session end events and then do your custom tasks when `count==0`

Comment: I suppose in our case it can be pretty good workaround. Thanks. But it will work only when we need to perform some action after test suite is complete, won't it?

Comment: @DotNetter this is just a workaround and you can keep the count on testrun/session event based on your need.